# Thoughtlessness

Tags: meditation

Sometimes, when I am focusing on the body or the breath, I have a feeling that thoughts have ceased. I am unsure whether I am suppressing or not, I don't feel that I am, but that I am merely focusing upon an object.

Should I worry about this lack of thoughts? Should I keep meditating even if very few thoughts arise?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a meditation teacher, you should ask that person. If you do not, or if the teacher cannot give a helpful answer, you should seek a meditation teacher who can.

Answer (score 2):

The development of calm (*samatha*) & concentration (*samadhi*) in meditation is based on the mind focusing on the breath without any thoughts. It is important to feel a soothing calm in this process.

Answer (score 0):

You better stick to only one meditation technique of a meditation master. Also it depends on how long you practice each session, to which interval already practiced so that to which level of concentration you achieved, it all depends. Sometimes stages of insight meditation go up and down and sometimes stick to one stage and cannot get through it if not enough concentration.  If you focusing on breathing in and out, focusing point to note mindfully at the tip of the nose , if other phenomenon  arise only if it is remarkable try to note mindfully as "know it, know it" if it disappears, noting breathing again. If you get concentration more and more, all your noting become so subtle that you noticed nothing. Sometimes just like lack of thought.  Then appear again clearer visualizing some phenomenon never seen before. Then all these disappear again slowly disintegrating into smaller ones. This time again sometimes so clear-minded and nondescribable feeling of experience.   Like that much more left. Not every one will have similar experience. Based on your previous experience from the beginning of practice and how closely done each session without hiatus so that how deep your concentration achieved it all depends.